# Odoo duplicate field value with server-action

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

How can I duplicate a value with a server action 
for example

field 1 : x_bedrag = 10 euro

field 2 : x_betaald = empty

Run server action -> field 2 becomes (x_betaald) = 10 euro
(model: x_drivers_lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:
Server actions

-> New -> Type model -> Set type of action to write on record

-> choose the record you want to copy to

-> set the value to the record you want to copy from
[image]